# Homemade ways to mute strings (eg hair scrunchie)

Tags: guitar, strings, mute

I've seen a ton of players using hair scrunchies, or similar soft bands to mute, or rather dampen strings.

What are some of the best ways to do this?  What works better vs what doesn't mute very well?

Comment: De gustibus non disputandam est.   To elaborate (not really :-) ),  res ipsa loquitur.

Comment: you mean it doesn't really make a difference what you use? I didn't make a direct statement to which you can say 'not really'

Comment: No, that phrase means "in matters of taste, there's no point in arguing," aka you should try different things and see what pleases you the most.  The "not really" refers to the fact that my second Latin phrase (Hunter S. Thompson's standard closing) has basically nothing to do with the first or your question.  It's a JOKE, [redacted] it!

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not that well versed in latin and therefore, didn't get it  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All depends on personal style. You can use the ties to mute strings or overtones you don't wish to ring, in which case the applicable tension depends on how hard you play. You can also use a product like the GruvGear Fretwraps to provide adjustable tension. I find muting overtones also works well when tracking bass-to-MIDI. Victor Wooten also uses a technique where he moves the tie to a certain spot on the neck and plays below it, producing an artificial harmonic.

It's all experimentation, though, really. Have fun!

Comment: That's what I said :-) .  What, you don't speak Latin? :-)

Comment: Evidently not. :)

Comment: Tempus Fugit mon capitan

Comment: @AlexanderTroup  "We don't have time for your games"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not worried about that, Jean-Luc. You only dislike me. There are others in the cosmos who truly despise me.